# Which function for finding if a string is in an array (VBA) is better?

Tags: arrays, string, vba, function

I have 2 functions that check to see if a string exists in an array. 
I don't know which is better and if there are any reasons to use one over the other. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

**function 1**

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

**function 2**

```
Function IsInArray(myArray As Variant, val As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer, found As Boolean
    found = False

    If Not Len(Join(myArray)) > 0 Then
        found = False
    Else
        For i = 0 To UBound(myArray)
            If myArray(i) = val Then
               found = True
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    IsInArray = found
End Function
```

Comment: You don't have to continue the loop in your second function after you set `found = True`.  Just do `IsInArray = True : Exit Function`

Comment: Those two functions do different things.  Using `Filter` will also match substrings, whereas your second function only returns true if there's an *exact* match.

Comment: thank you to both of you.  These comments help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do.

```
For each thing in Arr
    If instr(Thing, StringToBeFound) > 0 then msgbox thing
Next
```

Your second function uses a lot of memory with a big array.

This is what happens when you join strings. I don't know if Join function uses stringbuilding or not. I doubt it does as nothing else in basic does. So ordinary concatination shuffles a lot of bytes around memory.

**String Concatination**

And don't join strings one character at a time. See this from a VBScript programmer. It requires 50,000 bytes and many allocation and deallocation to make a 100 character string.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/20/53248.aspx

PS: We have the `Mid` statement in VBA (not to be confused with the `Mid` function) that allows string building as a generic solution to shuffling bytes. It only matters on large arrays/strings.

Comment: Did you benchmark this?  OP's function 1 should outperform this easily.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions should work. The first one is small and straightforward, and moreover it returns how many times the match was found.

The second solution has the advantage of being "under your control", since you know what exactly you are doing. For example, with a slight modification you can return the position of the first match. You can make it faster though by adding the statement "Exit For" after "found = true", since there is no need to check further...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to several people who input in this thread I was able to create this solution

```
Function IsInArrayyyy(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    For Each thing In arr
        If InStr(thing, stringToBeFound) > 0 Then
            If Len(thing) = Len(stringToBeFound) Then 'remove this if exact match not needed
                IsInArrayyyy = True: Exit Function
            End If  'remove this if exact match not needed
        End If
    Next
End Function
```